# Nuget spec editing values via command line switches

Tags: batch-file, cmd, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-spec

I'm making a library, and creating a nuget package using the `nuget spec` and `nuget pack` commands. However, every time I run `nuget spec`, I get a load of rubbish in the `.nuspec` file that I don't want (like 'SampleDependency') I was wondering if it's possible to add these values (Id, URL, etc.) via command line switches. From what I can see on the documentation, it's not possible, but I don't know if it's been left out or something similar. Also, if it isn't possible, how would I edit the `.nuspec` file in a batch to give it the values I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your question around command-line switches. There are no commands to pass in the values you want. If you are packing a csproj instead of an assembly, you do get [replacement token support](https://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-package) and automatic dependency generation.

If you want to pack assemblies, you should be able write your own batch/powershell scripts to make the changes you need. Easiest thing would be a generate a nuspec, create replacement tokens (E.g $id$ for ID) for the fields you want to change and a do a replace before pack.This way you can create the nuspec file once, set it up and then substitute the values on each pack.